# Next.jsで上手くreact-draft-wysiwygが動かない

Tags: reactjs, next.js

下記のページを参考に、Next.jsでreact-draft-wysiwygを導入しようと考えています。

[ブラウザ上で動くリッチなテキストエディタを、React Draft Wysiwygを使って手軽に実装する](https://harionote.net/2022/01/07/%E3%80%90react-draft-wysiwyg%E3%80%91%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A6%E3%82%B6%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%A7%E5%8B%95%E3%81%8F%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%83%81%E3%81%AA%E3%83%86%E3%82%AD%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%82%A8%E3%83%87/)

#### 実現したいこと

react-draft-wysiwygを動かして、入力内容を `const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState("");` で受け取りたい

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

エラーではないですが、なぜか
`const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState("");`
を記述し、
`<Editor editorState={editorState} 〜省略〜`

を追加すると、本番環境とローカル環境で記入できなくなります。（vercelで確認できます。）
このusestateがないと値を受け取れないので、実装したいのですが、原因がまだ分かっていません。
分かる方がいれば教えて頂きたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

https://sample-file.vercel.app/

github
https://github.com/takoyan33/sample-file

#### 該当のソースコード

JavaScript

```
import React, { useCallback, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const Editor = dynamic(
  () => import("react-draft-wysiwyg").then((mod) => mod.Editor),
  { ssr: false }
);

import { ContentState, convertToRaw, EditorState } from "draft-js";

import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";

export default function Home() {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState("");

  const handleImageUpload = useCallback(async (file) => {
    return await axios
      .post
      // fileをアップロードし、アップロード後の画像のurlを返す処理
      ()
      .then((response) => {
        return { data: { link: response } };
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return error;
      });
  }, []);

  console.log(editorState);

  return (
    <div className="container my-5">
      <Editor
        editorState={editorState}
        toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
        wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
        editorClassName="editorClassName"
        editorStyle={{
          border: "solid 1px lightgray",
          padding: "5px",
        }}
        localization={{ locale: "ja" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

draft-js のバージョンの問題ではないでしょうか？

react-draft-wysiwyg の公式ドキュメントでは、
draft-js 0.10.x が必要とかいてありました。

https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/docs